# Is it possible for a sub-panel in a custom control to accept controls from the designer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have created a simple test control inheriting from Tcustom control, which contains 2 panels. The first is a header aligned to the top and client panel aligned to alclient.

I would like the client panel to accept controls from the designer and although I can place controls on the panel, they are not visible at run time and they do not save properly when the project is closed.

The sample code for the control is as follows

```
unit Testcontrol;

interface
uses Windows,System.SysUtils, System.Classes,System.Types, Vcl.Controls,
     Vcl.Forms,Vcl.ExtCtrls,graphics,Messages;

type
  TtestControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FHeader:Tpanel;
    FClient:Tpanel;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(Aowner:Tcomponent);override;
    destructor Destroy;override;
  published
    property Align;
  end;

implementation

{ TtestControl }

constructor TtestControl.Create(Aowner: Tcomponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Fheader:=Tpanel.create(self);
  Fheader.Caption:='Header';
  Fheader.Height:=20;
  Fheader.Parent:=self;
  Fheader.Align:=altop;
  Fclient:=Tpanel.Create(Self);
  with Fclient do
  begin
    setsubcomponent(true);
    ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
    Align:=alclient;
    Parent:=self;
    color:=clwhite;
    BorderStyle:=bssingle;
    Ctl3D:=false;
    ParentCtl3D:=false;
    Bevelouter:=bvnone;
  end;
end;

destructor TtestControl.Destroy;
begin
  FHeader.Free;
  FClient.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

If I put a button on the test component, the structure shows it as part of the form and not a subcomponent of the test component....and then it doesnt work anyway.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I know this question is old and already answered, but I would also suggest taking a look at how the `TCategoryPanel` control works, as it basically does this. It redirects it's children to the surface inside it.

Answer (score 2):

After plenty of googling around, I found some information which allowed me to cobble together a solution that seems to work.

It seems there two procedures in the base class needs to be overridden to update the control.

The first is the a method called "Loaded" which is called when the streaming has ended.

It seems the streaming places all the sub-panel components placed by the designer on the base component, not on the panel they were originally parent to. So this routine manually reassigns the Parent properties after the loading process has finished.

The second method is called GetChildren, I couldn't find much information as to what this method actually does other than the rather cryptic text in the chm help. However I adapted the overridden code from another example I found on the web which had a similar requirement and it worked. So if anyone can provide some insight as to why this is necessary then that would be useful information.

I have pasted the complete source code for the sample custom component below so that anyone who has a similar requirement in the future, can use it as a starting template for their own components.

```
unit Testcontrol;

interface
uses Windows, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.ExtCtrls,graphics;

type
  TtestControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FHeader:Tpanel;
    FClient:Tpanel;
  protected
    procedure Loaded;override;
    procedure GetChildren(Proc:TGetChildProc; Root:TComponent);override;
  public
    constructor Create(Aowner:Tcomponent);override;
    destructor Destroy;override;
  published
    property Align;
  end;

implementation

{ TtestControl }

constructor TtestControl.Create(Aowner:Tcomponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Fheader:=Tpanel.create(self);
  Fheader.setsubcomponent(true);
  Fheader.Caption:='Header';
  Fheader.Height:=20;
  Fheader.Parent:=self;
  Fheader.Align:=altop;
  Fclient:=Tpanel.Create(Self);
  with Fclient do
  begin
    setsubcomponent(true);
    ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
    Align:=alclient;
    Parent:=self;
    color:=clwhite;
    BorderStyle:=bssingle;
    Ctl3D:=false;
    ParentCtl3D:=false;
    Bevelouter:=bvnone;
  end;
end;

destructor TtestControl.Destroy;
begin
  FHeader.Free;
  FClient.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TtestControl.Loaded;
var i:integer;
begin
  inherited;
  for i := ControlCount - 1 downto 0 do
   if (Controls[i] <> Fheader) and (Controls[i] <> Fclient) then
     Controls[i].Parent := Fclient;
end;

procedure TtestControl.GetChildren(Proc:TGetChildProc; Root:TComponent);
var i:integer;
begin
  inherited;
  for i := 0 to Fclient.ControlCount-1 do
    Proc(Fclient.Controls[i]);
end;

end.
```